# How to find the penultimate record in a group else find the last

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 relevant columns: `Serial_#`, `Action_Date` and `IG_Group`. I have a query that sorts by 2 of these columns - `Serial_#` and `Action_Date` so that the results have 1 or more entries per `Serial_#`. This tells me the dates that a serial was moved to a new group. Example

```
Serial_#     Action_Date     IG_Group
4000001      2016-04-08      Group J
4000001      2016-04-07      Group F
4000001      2016-03-14      Group B
5000002      2016-04-19      Group J
6000003      2016-04-08      Group J
6000003      2015-10-19      Group A
```

I am trying to find out which `IG_Group` a serial was in before it was in the one it's in now. And if there's only one entry (as in serial 5000002 above) then I want that entry

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for every record with window functions (which most databases support):

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(lag(ig_group) over (partition by serial_ order by action_date), 
from t;
```

For just the last one, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.serial_#
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ig_group end) as last_ig_group,
       coalesce(max(case when seqnum = 2 then ig_group end),
                max(case when seqnum = 1 then ig_group end)
               ) as prev_ig_group_if_any
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by serial_ order by action_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.serial_#;
```